# Magento 2: How can I check all modules installed using admin panel?

Tags: magento2, admin, third-party-module

There is a method to check my modules installed and enabled or disabled using just the admin panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Magento ˆ2.3

**System > Web Setup Wizard > Module Manager**

### Magento 2.2

You can access using the admin panel the route **Stores > Configuration > Advanced**, as the image below.
On that page, you can enable or disable some modules as well.

[image: magento 2 admin modules list]

**Notice that this is taken away from the admin panel since Magento 2.2.0.** Reference, https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/advanced-menu-missing/m-p/81393#M1973

Comment: For which Magento version, are you talking about? From Magento 2.2 onwards - Ability to disable module output has been removed from admin panel.

Comment: You need to set the develop mode to show up

Comment: Developer mode was for pre 2.2 versions. In 2.1 version you can view Modules list in admin in developer mode.

Comment: Not visible in M 2.3.1 (EE)

Comment: Hey @AjwadTaqvi, probably you're not in development mode.

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the replies above, there is no more admin control for Magento2 versions 2.2 and greater. In this instance use this CLI command from your M2 root to output the modules and status `php bin/magento module:status`.

Answer (score 3):

ON 2.3.x : **System > Web Setup Wizard > Module Manager**

Comment: There is no reason to access the setup wizard unless you are doing an initial install or an upgrade think the 2 prior answers were the best way to go about this

Comment: Web Setup Wizard was removed since 2.3.7